# Column width on Gridview not wrapping in edit mode

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

Issuse: Column width on Gridview not wrapping in edit mode

Header on 'preview' shows header text in neat columns that fit 1000px wide. As soon as I press edit the table expands past this size.

How do I force a maximum size of the table in edit view?

Code: CSS / VB.net

.aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1000px"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
    EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display - Please change your search."
    DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    EnableViewState="true" EnableModelValidation="True" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"  />
```

Example field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Login Name" SortExpression="UserName">
 <ItemTemplate>                   
  <%# Eval("UserName") %>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'/>
 </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

CSS (there is more but I believe this where I need to look)

The 100% to my mind works as 100% of the 1000px refered to in the grid as this works before I click edit.

```
.gridview { 
        font-family:"arial"; 
        background-color:#002649; 
        width: 100%; 
        font-size: small; 
        color: #658654;       
        table-layout:fixed;

}
```

Comment: you will have to specify width on textboxes in the edititemtemplate as well. it is the textboxes which are causing this because they get a default width which is larger than the column width on table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the grid view column width in ItemStyle and also width of TextBox. As e.g

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Login Name" SortExpression="UserName">
     <ItemTemplate>                   
          <%# Eval("UserName") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" width="200px" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'/>
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle width="200px"> </ItemStyle>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I thought you might say that :-( Can I put the width for both the textbox and itemstyle into CSS as one thing? (That way I can standardise most of the columns)

Comment: if u fix size from css then it will fix the size of all column and text box width. if it's ok with u then i can give example.